# Close reasons window overlaps review actions bar

Tags: bug, review, design, popups

When you click "close" in the review queue, it pops up a form with some options. If you scroll down, it covers the top bar. Instead, it should go in-between the Q&A and the top bar.

[image: gif of it happening]